# Screen GNU Script Bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, gnu-screen

I want to do a script, to automatize my tasks while I start my PC. 
The main idea is to use screen to do it.
I wrote this, but It doesn't work. Only it builded the first session and then nothing more.
This is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS angular sh -c 'cd Documents/segdet; ng serve --env=local'
screen -dmS jboss1 sh -x -c 'cd Documents/keycloak-2.3.0.Final/bin; ./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -b 0.0.0.0 &' 
screen -dmS jboss2 sh -x -c 'cd Documents/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin; ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use screen's `-d` option to get the screen session to disconnect after starting so it will move to the next one in the script.

Also using `-S` is useful to name the session so you can connect to the correct one later.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS angular sh -c 'cd Documents/file1; ng serve --env=local' 
screen -dmS jboss1 sh -x -c 'cd Documents/file2/bin; ./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -b 0.0.0.0 &' 
screen -dmS jboss2 sh -x -c 'wil' 'cd Documents/file3/bin; ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &'
```

This will start 3 screen sessions named angular, jboss1 and jboss2

Comment: I tried but It show me this "There is a screen on:
 2399.angular (08/09/17 16:01:43) (Detached)".

Comment: Which means it's started the screen instance called angular in the background

Comment: Are you sure the commands for the second 2 sessions actually work? Also if they return then the screen sessions will exit immediately and not show up in the list (`screen -ls`).